# Return XML or JSON from a REST controller based on request parameters

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot

This is my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public Result generateResult(@Valid @RequestBody Request request) throws JsonProcessingException {

    Result result = new Result();
    // some code here
    return result;
}
```

and this is my Request class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Request {

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    
    private String type = "application/json";
}
```

the controller produces the correct output based on the `Accept` header in the request sent by the client. However, I want to send no `Accept` header and only send the following request:

```
{
    "name": "my name",
    "type": "application/xml"
}
```

Then based on the `type` the correct format should be output. I tried to add `HttpServletResponse response` to the parameter list of the controller method and then set the content type like this:

```
response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, request.geType());
```

but it always returns json. any idea what else I should do?

Comment: Return [`ResponseEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the comments  I post this answer which worked for me. I changed my controller method like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Result> generateResult(@Valid @RequestBody Request request) 
    throws JsonProcessingException {

Result result = new Result();
// some code here
return ResponseEntity.accepted()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a standard Spring's ResponseEntity builder give you all needed variety:

```
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok(//any object for json structure)
                .headers(//any header)
                .build();
```

Instead .ok() you can you any other method (that's http status code)

or

> ```
>     HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
>     responseHeaders.set("MyHeader", "MyValue");
>     return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
> ```

Comment: when I set headers with this approach I get an error: header has private access.

Comment: Create new Header for example     HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("Any-Header", "Any-Value") and set responseHeaders into .headers(responseHeaders ). That's standart Spring api

Comment: I add additional info from spring documentation if you can't use ResponseEntityBuilder.